# How many levels are there in two-player mode in Lode Runner: The Legend Returns (1994)

Tags: lode-runner-the-legend-returns

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lode_Runner:_The_Legend_Returns), one-player mode has 150 levels.

How many levels are there in two-player mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this speedrun](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=23fd6O6bJDo), two-player coop has 30 levels.